# Calculate angle of the next point on a circle

Tags: circles, angle

Given a radius (r=100) and a distance (d=10) how can I calculate the angle of a point at a given straight-line distance (on a circle with that radius)?

The end result is to take a point on a circle and find the next point on the circumference of that circle in a straight line, so to most efficiently generate a set of points on the circle which are not so close or so far as to render a circle on screen with visible lines or excess points.

I am working in code with very little mathematical notation experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $n$th point $P_n$ has polar angle $a_n$, the $n+1$st point $P_{n+1}$ has polar angle:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\alpha \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \  \alpha=\sin^{-1}(\tfrac{d}{2r}) \iff \sin \alpha = \tfrac{d}{2r}$$

this last relationship coming from elementary trigonometry on isosceles triangle $OP_nP_{n+1}$ whose leg is $r$, and half base $d/2$ (remember : sine = opp/hyp).

Comment: My understanding is that the middle section in code would be: angle = sin( pow( d / (2*radius), -1 ) ). Is this correct?

Comment: No: $\sin^{-1}$ is meant for arcsine, the reciprocal funtion of $\sin$, not $1/sin$. Maybe, on your system, arcsine is denoted "asin" ... this is the notation is many languages.

Comment: How about this? angle = asin( d / (2*radius) )

Comment: Yes, that's it !

Comment: The angle returned is in radians, yes?

Comment: Yes, as is the case most of time in theoretical contexts .

Comment: I had for gîtes a  2 factor.  I just placed it in my answer.  Sorry !

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but my code works now, so thank you so much :)